# Twitter feed has stopped working, Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest, accesscontrolexception

This is my site here:

[Income Brokers](http://www.incomebrokers.com)

Up until recentley my Tweets where displaying fine, however now I am getting this error in the console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://www.incomebrokers.com/js/get_tweets.php. Origin
>   http://incomebrokers.com is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I don't know why it has just stopped working...Can anyone help me out?

This is my `get_tweets.php` script:

```
session_start();
require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
$twitteruser = "xxxxxxx";
$notweets = 30;
$consumerkey="xxxxxxxxxx";
$consumersecret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$accesstoken="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$accesstokensecret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret){

    $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);

    return $connection;

}

$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);

echo json_encode($tweets);
```

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are effectively requesting from another domain.

The request is coming from http://incomebrokers.com while you are loading http://www.incomebrokers.com (with www in it). Because the url with and without www are seen as different URL's you need to make sure to append www in both cases.

There is another workaround. In your PHP file, place this right under your `<?php` tag.

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

This will allow requesting from 'other' domains.

Comment: Excellent, problem solved thank you very much. Will accept answer in 5 mins!

Comment: Strangely though this problem only began tonight, up until a few hours ago it was working perfectly

Comment: Check the accepted answer on this page on why these kind of errors occur http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work

Comment: another alternative would be just to source the url as '/js/get_tweets.php' then it won't matter.